# How can I physically demonstrate potential difference in a circuit to a 14 year old?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, definition

Children of this age have a fair idea about current, resistance, and batteries. Potential difference is a thing that cannot be felt or physically visualized. A teenager asked me if he can touch 'potential difference' (or 'potential), if he can put potential in his pocket?
How can I help him visualize potential without getting out of scope (and the definition - 'the work done to bring a unit charge...' is certainly beyond his wild imaginations.)

Answer (score 2):

Make make an analogy between gravitational potential energy, which is easy to visualize, and electrical potential energy. By doing this all the knowledge they have about a simpler subject will help them understand a more complicated one. Hold a ball and drop it. Draw what happened on the board, showing that the more potential (voltage) the fastest the ball falls (current). If you really want to push the analogy, air resistance could be electrical resistance.

Comment: Again, what is 'potential' in gravitational potential energy?

Comment: @Swami Hold a ball and drop it. Draw what happened on the board, showing that the more potential (voltage) the fastest the ball falls (current). If you really want to push the analogy, air resistance could be electrical resistance.

Comment: right, well said.